# .NETによる大容量ファイル(圧縮後のファイル容量が2GB)の圧縮/解凍方法について

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

**実行環境:**
Windows
Oracle Database 19c (Cloud)

**開発言語:**
VB.net (.Net Framewordk4.8)

#### やりたいこと

expdpにてDBを「dmp」形式でエクスポートします。
エクスポートしたdmpファイルをコンソールアプリより自動的にZIP形式で圧縮/解凍を行いたいです。

#### 懸念点

.NET Framework 4.5以降では標準で圧縮/解凍機能が用意されていますが
圧縮後のファイル容量が2GBを超える場合に上手くいきません。
ちなみにdmpファイルの分割は行わない想定です。

何か良い方法または扱えるライブラリなどご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: .NET 4.0 以後は `GZipStream` は 4GiB 超を取り扱えるようになったはずなのでそもそも 2GiB ってのが何かおかしいっス FAT FS 上で試験してないっスか？

Comment: うまくいかない場合に何かエラーメッセージ等が表示されているようであれば、それらも質問に含めておくと回答のヒントになると思います。(質問は後からでも編集できます)

Comment: gzipでなくzipということですかね？

Comment: 774RR様　.NETの制限というよりzipの制限ですね。圧縮前が4GB、圧縮後が2GBが上限かと思います。圧縮後の話をしていました。言葉足らずで申し訳ないです。
cubick♦様　ご指摘有難うございます。次回から気を付けます。
sayuri様　zipです。

回答頂き解決しました。有難うございました。

Comment: 774RR さんが言及しているのは FAT32 というファイルシステムの制限についてであり、ZIPファイルに限定したものではありません。FAT32 上では「1ファイルで2GBまで」という制限があるので、プログラムでの対応と合わせて保存先のファイルシステムも念の為確認した方がよいと思います (単に Windows としか書かれていないため。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.NET Core` または `.Net 5` ではZIPファイルのDeflate64フォーマットに対応しているため2GB以上のアーカイブも扱えます。

`.NET Framework` で2GB以上のZIPファイルを扱うのであれば、[SevenZipSharp](https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp) などを使用するのが良いと思います。

Comment: SevenZipSharpを使用することにしました。有難うございました。